# Connecting my netbook to my TV

Tags: netbook, tv

I am trying to connect my netbook to my TV. I use an **ASUS Eee PC 1005HA**. It has a VGA exit. My TV only has RCA and S-VIDEO input. So i bought a VGA to RCA/S-VIDEO cable.
And I bought a 3.5 mm to RCA cable, for the audio. Finally, I used a single RCA cable to connect the computer to the TV.

I plug the 3.5mm to my leptop, and the RCA to the TV. I plug the VGA adapter to my computer, and the RCA to the TV. Everything is conviently color-coded. But all I get is a black screen. I tried it on a diffrent television (with the same connections), but with no results.

Is there anything I am missing? Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the connector you likely bought only supports computers with a "TV out" capability. For all other computers you need a VGA to composite video converter.

See [here](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=104&cp_id=10401&cs_id=1040113&p_id=2509&seq=1&format=2) for a more complete explanation.

Comment: good thinking, i actually thought he bought a converter. the Eee doesn't have native composite/s-video output through the VGA port.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd monitor might be just an extension of your monitor which means you need to drag the items you want to show beyond your regular netbook screen.  For me, I need to drag it to the way right and it will show on the TV.  Hope it helps.

Also, check your display properties/settings.

Answer (score 0):

did you select the correct AV-input channel on the TV?

did you activate the VGA out on your Eee PC (Fn + F8 )?

*note: the Fn key functionality requires AsAcpiSvr.exe to be running, if necessary reinstall the ACPI driver.*

Comment: Yes, I checked all the AV inputs several times.
And yes, I activated the VGA out (it's Actually Fn + F8, not that it matters). Still nothing but a black, depressing screen.

Comment: VGA out works on a computer monitor?

Comment: Didn't try it. And I don't have access to a computer monitor to try it right now.